# Kendo UI numeric textbox displays "g"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox, kendo-ui

I have a kendoui numeric textbox as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(dvm => d.OffId)
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fullWidth" })                                                    
.Format("g")
.Max(64)
.Min(0))
```

When this gets rendered, it displays "g" in the textbox. When I enter edit mode, it displays "0". It jumps back to "g" when I exit edit mode. (clicking outside the textbox)

How do I get it to display 0 always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that `g` is a valid format for numbers. According KendoUI documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting) seems to be a format for dates *g - General date/time pattern (short time) ("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt" for en-US)*

Check [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting) for valid number formats.

Comment: I'm following the number formats here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: But you are formatting the value in the client (KendoUI) not in the server (Microsoft). Try using one of the formats in KendoUI list to see if they work. If so, you have to use KendoUI formats: sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [initializing](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#configuration-value) the value?

**.Value(0)**

Answer (score 0):

Knows it's an old question, but I am writting this for other with same issue.
I have also tried this with format: 'd' and when writting 0, it just displays d.
Instead I use format:'n0' that works and works for 'g' as well.